# Can't debug using Azure SDK for Node.js

Tags: node.js, azure, sdk

I am absolutely frustrated by the Azure SDK for years now I have been using it and this problem of outputting errors to the log file still arises:

```
Application has thrown an uncaught exception and is terminated:
Error: ENOENT, no such file or directory 'C:\DWASFiles\Sites\pazooza\VirtualDirectory0\site\wwwroot\iisnode\RD00155D4313F9-20848-stdout-Tue Mar 26 2013 03:10:56 GMT+0000 (GMT Standard Time).txt'
    at Object.openSync (fs.js:240:18)
    at Object.writeFileSync (fs.js:628:15)
    at SyncWriteStream.<anonymous> (D:\Program Files (x86)\iisnode\interceptor.js:181:20)
    at Object.<anonymous> (console.js:25:18)
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (C:\DWASFiles\Sites\pazooza\VirtualDirectory0\site\wwwroot\utils\facebook.js:69:21)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:88:20)
    at HTTPParser.parserOnMessageComplete [as onMessageComplete] (http.js:130:23)
    at CleartextStream.socketOnData [as ondata] (http.js:1288:20)
    at CleartextStream._push (tls.js:375:27)
    at SecurePair.cycle (tls.js:734:20)
```

As you see the error occurs because the fs object is trying to find something that is on the c: drive, what is the c: drive pointing to my local machine got to do with the logging system that is suppose to be in the Azure Websites?

And D:\Program Files (x86)\iisnode\interceptor.js

What is that all about shouldn't it be pointing to a resource in the Azure Cloud Websites Instance?

Can anyone from Azure SDK tell me how to make this error go away.

I asked this months and months ago and we thought we had it fixed by now its back again ... very frustrating Microsoft... wtf are you guys doing to make our lives easier?

My other questions on here that lead to this problem:

[Webmatrix 2 broken](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12312625/webmatrix-2-broken) and
[Windows Azure Node.js Internal Server Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13637272/windows-azure-node-js-internal-server-error)

My node.js web.config file looks like this:

```
<configuration>
     <system.webServer>
          <handlers>
               <!-- indicates that the server.js file is a node.js application to be handled by the iisnode module -->
               <add name="iisnode" path="server.js" verb="*" modules="iisnode"/>
          </handlers>
          <rewrite>
               <rules>
                    <!-- Don't interfere with requests for node-inspector debugging -->
                    <rule name="NodeInspector" patternSyntax="ECMAScript" stopProcessing="true">                    
                        <match url="^server.js\/debug[\/]?" />
                    </rule>

                    <!-- First we consider whether the incoming URL matches a physical file in the /public folder -->
                    <rule name="StaticContent">
                         <action type="Rewrite" url="public{{REQUEST_URI}}"/>
                    </rule>

                    <!-- All other URLs are mapped to the Node.js application entry point -->
                    <rule name="DynamicContent">
                         <conditions>
                              <add input="{{REQUEST_FILENAME}}" matchType="IsFile" negate="True"/>
                         </conditions>
                         <action type="Rewrite" url="server.js"/>
                    </rule>

               </rules>
          </rewrite>
          <!-- You can control how Node is hosted within IIS using the following options  -->
          <iisnode
            loggingEnabled="true"
            devErrorsEnabled="true"
         />
     </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Any help or advice as to why this error shows up when I set logginEnabled="true" would be appreciated.

When I set loggingEnabled to false no errors and the site runs fine, but when its turn on everything is effed up!

Answer (score 0):

Could you file an issue under: https://github.com/windowsazure/iisnode ?

Sounds like this is an issue with IISNode logging ? We may be able to help you there with further details on the issue.

Andre